# How to update a table view from another view

Tags: uitableview, iphone-sdk-4.1

I have problem like - Have a table view with data, it also have a search button in the tab bar. search button will lead to another view, there i specifies the constraints and press a "filter now" button which display the data based on the constraints in the former table view.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading iOS Human Interface Guidelines as what you are doing may not pass Apple's strict rules.

iOS Human Interface Guidelines describes the guidelines and principles that help you design a superlative user interface and user experience for your iOS app.